# SQL Query to find out the non weekends (Monday-Friday) dates of a week from a variable date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am writing a SQL Query to find out the non weekends dates (i.e. Monday-Friday) of a week from a variable date.

Basically, it should show the dates which are not coming in weekends (Saturday & Sunday) of the week of a given date.

E.g. If the given date is 6th January, 2021. Then the output date should be between  4th-8th January, 2021.
i.e the `Week_Start_Date` should be **2021-01-04** and `Week_End_Date` should be **2021-01-08**.

I am writing below codes to find out the count of non-weekend days by referring a date and also writing a query to find out the `Week_Start_Date` & `Week_End_Date` using the referring date, but unable to combine both of these.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2021/01/04'
SET @EndDate = '2021/01/08'


SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [Week_Start_Date],  
DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [Week_End_Date] ;
```

**EDIT:**

I am getting the required output using below SQL query :-

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0)
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),4)
```

Comment: For such requirement, it is best to use a `calendar` table. Do a search, there are lots of reference on this topic

Comment: **@All : Kindly do not give a negative vote without sharing your views. It gets difficult to understand what's wrong. SQL queries can be written in any way and not exactly your way. I have written all the queries clearly and even shared the answer too**

Comment: @AmarKumar Do your research. Simple searching will find **many** discussions about "work days" (which is a misleading term which you may eventually come to understand) and how to calculate intervals based on them. Sometimes businesses are forced to close for reasons beyond their control. And if you are concerned with DATES, why do you use datetime variables? THINK!

Comment: And you do yourself no favor by using the cryptic abbreviations for datepart - and you use them inconsistently. You don't save any time using "wk" rather than "week" but the latter is far more readable. Lastly using mathematical operators is also not a good idea - perhaps that is why you used a kludge (datetime datatypes) to avoid writing code that works with date datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the required output using below SQL query :-

```
SELECT DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),0)
SELECT DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),4)
```